# https access to SO

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

It's 2013, about time to have this already. Pretty please.

Most major websites do this already and it doesn't seem to take more than a couple per cent of any type of resources that they have.

[Google, 3 years ago (so about 2 generations ago in Moore time)](http://www.imperialviolet.org/2010/06/25/overclocking-ssl.html)

> If there's one point that we want to communicate to the world, it's that SSL/TLS is not computationally expensive any more. Ten years ago it might have been true, but it's just not the case any more. You too can afford to enable HTTPS for your users.

Comment: Yes. It may not seem like a big deal, but seeing that magical https in my browser bar gives me warm fuzzies.

Comment: You really don't know what you're asking for here...we are working on it but it's nowhere near as simple as everyone asking on meta seems to think it is.  Maybe it's time for a post explaining just what has to be in place for us to go full TLS.

Comment: wtf @ben?! Why did you delete my edit explaining why this shouldn't be marked as a duplicate??

Comment: @eddi, it wasn't deleted, just edited out. It's noise and a thinly disguised rant that's not needed. If you're uncomfortable with posts being edited, you're on the wrong site.

Comment: by that logic all feature requests could be considered rants

Comment: @eddi - your edit was saying we don't look at old feature requests and none of the reasoning still applies, you're wrong on both.  We are however working on TLS - but it's far more complicated than you think.

Comment: @NickCraver: Having an explanation (maybe on the blog?) about all that, what is needed and what you need to look out for and such, would be really great! Less from the "I want SO to have SSL" but more from the "You want to go full encrypted? Let me show you the pain that awaits you".

Comment: I rolled-back your edit because it added nothing to either this question or the duplicate and made a number of, incorrect, assumptions and wasn't a particularly constructive edit. If you have something to add to your question please feel free but try to keep it pleasant, less accusatory and ensure that it adds something to the argument. _"Having https access is important both for security *and* privacy reasons"_ just re-hashes everything that's been discussed before and accusing people of missing the point entirely because of this isn't that nice of you.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby - I should, maybe if I find time today or next week...our pains are much higher because the number of domains and one endpoint for all that traffic (and CPU load of negotiation) as it stands.

Comment: @NickCraver please post a link here if you do.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby - I found time to blog about it here: http://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/

Comment: Update: we're there now. https://nickcraver.com/blog/2017/05/22/https-on-stack-overflow/